# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node', on append on of an html div

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

I am trying to create a **To-Do list** with basic js 
I have tried `adding` and `deleting` operation for the list 
 
on `adding` I am getting this below **error** even though the items get added
 **error** :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I am trying to `append (addNewData.innerHTML)` the HTML to the parent div `data-list`
can someone guide me, why I am getting this issue?

there are some more issues in this, currently on which I am working on

**Code Snippet**

```js
function getData() {
    var dataList = document.getElementById('add-items').value;
    console.log("id :" + dataList);


    // check if the input filed is empty           
    if (dataList == 0) {
        alert("Please add something to the List");
        console.log("if statement")
    } else {
        // add item to the list
        var addNewData = document.getElementById('data-list');
        addNewData.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="add-item added-item-list item-lists d-flex align-center f-wrap">
                        <div class="item-added f-grow"> ` + dataList + ` </div>
                        <div class="add-icon remove-data" onclick="removeRow(this)">
                            <p>Delete</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `
        var b = addNewData.appendChild('addNewData.innerHTML');
 document.getElementById('add-items').value='';
       

        // update pending status               
        var pendingDataCount = document.getElementById('pending-task').innerHTML;
        var getId = document.getElementById("pending-task");
        var spans = getId.getElementsByTagName("span");
        for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            console.log("for statement")
            var spanVal = spans[i].innerHTML;
            console.log("span val :" + spanVal);
            var newSpanVal = document.getElementsByClassName('added-item-list').length + 1;
            console.log("newSpanVal :" + newSpanVal);

            var pendingDataCount = document.getElementById('pending-task');
            pendingDataCount.innerHTML = `
                        <p>You have <span>` + newSpanVal + `</span> pending tasks </p>
                    `
            var c = pendingDataCount.appendChild('pendingDataCount.innerHTML');
        }
    }

}

function removeRow(input) {
    document.getElementById('data-list').removeChild(input.parentNode);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #68EACC 0%, #497BE8 100%);
     height: 100vh;
     text-align: center;
}
 .form-wrapper {
     background: #ffffff;
     max-width: 500px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 20px 30px;
     width: 100%;
     box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
 .form-wrapper h1 {
     text-align: left;
}
 .add-item {
     margin: 15px 0;
     font-weight: 600;
     color: #ffffff;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .add-item input, .item-added {
     padding: 10px 15px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     border: 2px solid #F2F2F2;
     border-radius: 5px;
     color: #000;
}
 .add-icon {
     background: #8E49E9;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 77px;
}
 .add-icon:hover {
     background-color: #55A6DD;
}
 .item-added {
     text-align: left;
}
 .item-lists {
     background: #F2F2F2;
}
 .remove-data {
     padding: 11px;
     background: #E74D3D;
}
 .remove-data:hover {
     opacity: 0.8;
     background: #E74D3D;
}
 .d-flex{
     display: flex;
}
 .align-center{
     align-items: center;
}
 .justify-center{
     justify-content: center;
}
 .f-wrap{
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .m-auto{
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 .f-grow{
     flex-grow: 1;
}
 p{
     margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: `appendChild` expects a `Node`, not a string. Details [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). You may want [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) or the newer [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

Comment: Separately, though, why are you trying to duplicate the `innerHTML` of `addNewData`? You've used `+=` when assigning to it, which while not best practice would mostly work for adding to the end of it. Why then try to further add it back again?